# Destructing nested object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to use object destructing for simplyfing my code. I am getting data from server and the resolve is object:

```
data = {
  current: {
     humidity: 73
  }
}
```

Final function should looks like this, but this does not work:

```
extractData({data.current.humidity: humidity  }) {
            return { humidity };
        }

extractData(data);
```

How to do function for this kind of object?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Destructuring patterns are just like object literals, so you don't use a dot, you use nesting (also, the name of the variable referring to the object [`data`] isn't relevant):

```
// (I assume this is a method in a class; otherwise, add `function`)
extractData({current: {humidity}}) {
    return { humidity };
}
```

Live Example:

```js
function extractData({current: {humidity}}) {
    return { humidity };
}

const data = {
  current: {
     humidity: 73
  }
};

console.log(extractData(data));
```

Note that I've kept your return value there, which is an *object* with a `humidity` property. If you just want the *value* of humidity, don't use `{}` around it:

```
// (I assume this is a method in a class; otherwise, add `function`)
extractData({current: {humidity}}) {
    return humidity;
}
```

Live Example:

```js
function extractData({current: {humidity}}) {
    return humidity;
}

const data = {
  current: {
     humidity: 73
  }
};

console.log(extractData(data));
```

---

I assumed you *wanted* a function, but [as Rittoo says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63266122/157247), you don't need one if all you want to do is get the value of `humidity`; see their answer for an example.

Comment: FWIW, I go into destructuring in some depth in Chapter 7 of my new book; see my profile for details if you're interested.

Answer (score 3):

Or you can simply use following format to get the humidity from the data without calling a function.

```
const {current: { humidity}} = data;
```

Comment: Good point, it didn't occur to me they were only using the function for the destructuring. (They may well not be, but from the name it does look a bit like that.)